# How to hide field using PHP?

Tags: php, drupal

I created a new field (Sort Weight) for a content type and wanted to hide this on the back-end when you go and edit the content type. I was told there is a PHP hook preprocess function that could be added the template.php file.

See image for reference:[image: Sort Weight]

Thanks!

Comment: What is your Drupal version? Please, add the relevant tag.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the [hook `form_alter`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) in your module. In this hook, you have to check the `form_id` (usually named like `{your content type}_node_form`). Then, you could alter the `$form` to make your field as "hidden".

Here is an example. Be sure to replace :

- `MYMODULE`: your module name
- `your_content_type_node_form`: the form ID
- `your_field_name`: The key in the `$form` for your field.

Code:

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
{
    if ($form_id == 'your_content_type_node_form') {
      $form['your_field_name']['#type'] = 'hidden';
    }
}
```